# Use string as Class Association Name Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that returns the name of an association as a string.This is the code for that:

```
def get_assoc_name
  Assoc.find(1).assoc_name
end

## Returns "foo"
```

Another model class ("Bar") has_one "Foo" (:foo). I am trying to use the result from the "get_assoc_name" to indicate that I want to access the association like so:

```
def get_bar_foo
  Bar.find(1)."#{get_assoc_name}"
end

## Should instantiate Bar.foo
```

The above is one of my many failed attempts. I know that you can use "constantize" to initiate a new class from a string, but how do I use a string to call an association?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method as :

```
def get_bar_foo
  Bar.find(1).public_send get_assoc_name
end
```

When you have *method* name as *Symbol* or *String*, you can call them using the method [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) if the method is public method, or [*send*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) when the method is *private* method.

Comment: This does exactly what I required! Thanks

Comment: @Herm I just updated the answer, String interpolation is not needed.